# intent does not launch any activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-studio

In my `%MainActivity` I have this

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                    LoginSignupActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);

        ....
    }
```

In fact, the intent is wrapped by a some authentication check but to debug I deleted it, but this method doesn't launch any `LoginSignupActivity`. Could someone help ?

Edit:

Here's the entire `onCreate` method

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                LoginSignupActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);

        setActionBarListNavigation();
        setupDrawer();
        setupContainer();
    }
```

`MainActivity extends CustomActivity` (which lods data from  `AsyncLoader`) and this last `Activity` inherits from `FragmentActivity` and has an `onCreate` method

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        theme = getAppTheme();
        setupActionBar();
    }
```

with

```
protected void setupActionBar()
    {
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(theme));
    }
```

At last

Comment: Do you get any errors/crash?

Comment: @Elenasys of course I have `<activity android:name=".authenticator.LoginSignupActivity">
        </activity>` in my manifest

Comment: **Off-topic**: you really shouldn't respond with "Of course" to everything, it may come off rude. **On-topic**:are there any errors or it just does nothing? If it doesn't crash then you may need to show more of your code in `onCreate()`. Also, have you set a breakpoint in the next `Activity` to be sure it doesn't start then finish for some reason?

Comment: @codeMagic Sorry I didn't mean to be rude. I have just edited my post.

Comment: I didn't think you did which is why I was polite in letting you know some may take it that way...no worries. I will take a look in a minute

Comment: can you post logcat error

Comment: @codeMagic I think it has nothing to do with the intent pb, because I deleted all what was inside the onCreate method, and guess what, the project compiled and is running fine in the emulator. I think is some cache issue, isn't it ?

Comment: You deleted everything, put it all back in, and now it works?

Comment: no, I deleted all what was inside the method, and despite of that it compiled and the app launched in the emulator, showing some `Activity` Isn't it weird ?

Comment: It is weird but I just read that you are using AS. You should indicate that in your posts. I don't know your programming experience but if you are new I, along with many veteran developers and Google, would recommend you use a different IDE for now as it is still new, buggy, and in a pre-lease version. It has many bugs to work out still that you won't get with other IDE's and **if** you are new, it will be hard to tell what are your mistakes and what are bugs in the IDE

Comment: Ok thank you, so I will go back to `ÌntelliJ`!

Comment: @codeMagic Btw, why do you think I was downvoted

Comment: I was actually curious about that myself. I would guess because you didn't post much information at first and you left out that you **did** have `startActivity()` so maybe people thought it you didn't do your research. I don't think it deserved to be downvoted but nobody asked me. We will see if we can balance that out a little

Comment: Going back to IntelliJ is probably wise. I've never used it myself but AS is based off of it so keep using that until AS comes out with at least v. 1.0 and your transition to it should be fairly easy.

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                    LoginSignupActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

register your all activity in manifest.xml

```
<activity android:name=".LoginSignupActivity"/>
```

Just had this problem, I needed to add my custom jar `library` to the `build.gradle` file:

```
dependencies {
    compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
    ADD FILE HERE   
}


/**
 * A {@code TaskSelectionException} is thrown when the tasks to execute cannot be selected due to some user input
 * problem.
 */
public class TaskSelectionException extends InvalidUserDataException {
    public TaskSelectionException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry i t was a typo. Of course, it doesn't work besides I put startActivity(intent); !

Comment: based on your post these two reason is major...otherwise post your full code

Comment: Sorry, I am very new to `android-studio`. So, my app is running normally (except it doesn't show the login screen). But when I launch `gradle compileDebug --stacktrace` I get this error `org.gradle.execution.TaskSelectionException: Task 'compileDebug' is ambiguous in root project 'Feeder'`. How can you explain that !

Comment: I think it has nothing to do with the intent pb, because I deleted all what was inside the onCreate method, and guess what, the project compiled and is running fine in the emulator. I think is some cache issue, isn't it ?

Answer (score 0):

add:  `startActivity(intent);`

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginSignupActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

and add LoginSignupActivity into your Manifest.xml

```
 <activity
            android:name=".LoginSignupActivity"
            android:label="Login" >
```

Answer (score 0):

You are launching an Activity during "onCreate" - you will not see your main activity (it never reaches "onStart" or "onResume").

So, if you are having problems, it is not in your MainActivity, it is in the other one, LoginSignupActivity.